# Android - downloading compressed answer from http

Tags: android, compression, gzip

I am trying to get compressed data from server. The guy that programmed the server told me, that he uses ZLIB library on his iPhone, and the gzcompress on server. I was trying to find any suitable way to get that data, but it ends up with info "java.io.IOException: unknown format (magic number 9c78)" while creating GZIPInputStream object. Finally I've reached point, where I had data as a String. It was compressed, so I used that answer to decompress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963668/419308 . But that code doesn't work. "in.read()" returns -1 at the beginning.

Anyone has any idea why there's -1 ? Or maybe a better way to get the compressed data?

EDIT:
I tried adding file to project and reading from that file. in.read() didn't return -1

EDIT2: According to [jJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633482/419308) I've tried this code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet( urlTeam );
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute( request );
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream stream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent( entity );

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( stream );
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( reader );

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.delete( 0, sb.length() );
String input;
while ( ( input = buffer.readLine() ) != null )
{
     sb.append( input );
}
```

But the answer is still compressed (or unreadable)

Comment: -1 is returned if there is nothing to read

Comment: So that code is not correct? I'm sure the passed String was not empty

Comment: from the api "the actual number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the compressed input stream is reached"

Comment: have you tried reading in your own zipped file to make sure it is not server side where something is going wrong.

Comment: I tried to, but after adding file to assets or res/raw, I couldn't compile project because of errors (Unable to add '<path>/xxx.json.gz': Zip add failed, ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '<path>\bin\resources.ap_', and ERROR: packaging of '<path>\bin\resources.ap_' failed). I'll try to find a solution for that and check that file

Comment: I updated question. File was readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on android you should use either [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) which handles decompression (and http encoding headers) for you from GingerBread on or [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) (for older android versions) that has helper methods like getUngzippedContent and modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse.

This is a good summary [Android HTTP clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Comment: I updated question with code containing AndroidHttpClient, which still brings me nothing.. Maybe there's something wrong?

Comment: I used getUngzippedContent() method from class AndroidHttpClient. Problem is that it won't work on lower Androids, but then I will download uncompressed data :-) Thanks for your guides, jJ :-)